# SQL Alchemy: How to bulk update values from a list of dicts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to update a table 'Salary' which has fields:

```
employeeId,
Salary
```

Now, I have updated values for each employee in a python dictionary, something like:

```
[
{employeeId:1,Salary:10000},
{employeeId:2,Salary:15000}
]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this update in a single SQL Alchemy update query rather than executing many update statements one by one

Comment: you can build a bulk insert statement so you only have to do one SQL query, but not sure you can form that statement without looping over your dict.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute : "whether this is passed as a single dictionary, or a list of dictionaries, determines whether the DBAPI cursor’s execute() or executemany() is used to execute the statement."

Comment: yeah..thats what i want on SQL query..probably I didnt communicate well in the original question. Let me edit that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will assume that you already have the table mapped like Salary and that **employeeId** is your primary key. So, all you have to do, is use the same dict:

```
[
  {employeeId:1,Salary:10000},
  {employeeId:2,Salary:15000}
]
```

and use the function [bulk_update_mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings)

```
session.bulk_update_mappings(
                Salary,
                [{employeeId:1,Salary:10000},
                 {employeeId:2,Salary:15000}]
            )
```

In this function, the primary id is required to be in the dict because this will be your filter and the other keys (columns) will be updated with the value that you have defined in the dict.

*PS: Sorry about my english.*

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Looks like this is what I need. I will try and let you know. But meanwhile, I will accept this answer.